# Alter word boundary

Tags: regex, perl, word-boundary

I currently have the following:

```
$_[0] =~ s/***regex here***(*SKIP)(*F)|\b($concatenated_variables)\b/\$$1/g;
```

`$concatenated_variables` contains variable names delimited by a `|`.

This is working fine EXCEPT, I don't want the substitution to occur if the match found by `\b($concatenated_variables)\b` already has a `$` before it.

For example:

`$concatenated_variables = count|a|var3`

`$_[0] = for count in range(3): print count; print "hello"; ++a`

If I use:

```
$_[0] =~ s/(?:['"](?:[^'"]*?(?:\\")*)*["'])(*SKIP)(*F)|(?<!\$)($concatenated_variables)\b/\$$1/g;
```

I get:

```
for coun$t in range(3): prin$t coun$t; prin$t "yayay"; ++$a
```

whereas I should get:

```
for $count in range(3): print $count; print "yayay"; ++$a
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Negative look-behind?

Comment: @choroba Thanks. I just tried using a negative look-behind. I have updated my question to show the result. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Your example works for me, I get: `for $count in range(3): print $count; print "hello"; ++$a`

Comment: @M42 Yes.. you're right. I tried it in isolation and it works. Must be something wrong with my code elsewhere. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
$concatenated_variables = qr/(?<!\$)(var1|var2|var3)/;
```